# Flutter / Dart FFI - Multiple files

Tags: flutter, cmake, ffi

This [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21512310-calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-with-dart-ffi) shows how to add C code to a Flutter project. This works (tested locally), but consists of only one file 'weather.c' in the example. If a larger library of several C files is to be embedded, do all C files have to be listed in the CMake list? The functions to start are all in one C file. This C file is the only reference to other C files.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)  


add_library( 
            weather
            SHARED
            ../../src/weather.c
)
```

Comment: Yes, you could compile several source files into single library by listing all these files in `add_library` call. This is not specific to Flutter, but this is how CMake works.